# How do I prevent PyCharm from creating a virtualenv every time I start a new project?

Tags: python, pycharm

I am a python hobbyist and installed pycharm to work on a number of projects. Every time I start a new project, pycharm community edition creates a new virtualenv without any packages. So for each small project, I have to install numpy, matplotlib, scikit etc again and again. This is irritating. How can this feature be disabled ?

I tried to search for this question but did not find it. Sorry if it is a duplicate.

Comment: This might be annoying, but it is good practice. Just an aside.

Comment: @erip: For a good user experience it should ask the user to either choose an existing virtual env or to create a new one.

Answer (score 5):

You need to hit the little triangle next to "Project Interpreter" under the Location.  Then hit the radio button for existing interpreter.

[image: PyCharm new Project]